# Passing a message into an action in Spinrg MVC controller from an interceptor

Tags: spring-mvc, interceptor

**One of a controller's action**

```
@RequestMapping("/user/login")
public String loginPage(String errorMessage, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);

    return "/view/loginPage";
}
```

**A snippet of viewPage.jsp**

```
<div id="alertError">Failed to get data because : ${errorMessage}</div>
```

**A snipper of my interceptor**

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    User user = (User)session.getAttribute("user")

    if ( user == null ) {
        response.sendRedirect("/user/login.do");
    }
}
```

**Okay time to explain.**

The interceptor checks a session and redirects to the signin page if session is null. I want to display a message `your session was expired. Please sign in` after the complete redirection.

But in the interceptor, I can't find any way to pass the message to the `loginPage` action. How can I do that?

FYI, Directly calling the `loginPage` method is not an answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your message as query parameter.

```
response.sendRedirect("/user/login.do?errMessage=yourMessage");
```

And in the controller side it can be retrieved as,

```
@RequestMapping("/user/login")
public String loginPage(@RequestParam("errMessage") String errMessage, Model model) {
```

Comment: I'm not looking for the `GET` way either.

Comment: Are you allowed to change your method signature ? If so, you can construct a request object, set the error message attribute and forward the request object to your loginPage() method where you can get back the message attribute.